# Syntax of establishing JFrame. Which is correct?

Tags: java, swing, inheritance, jframe, composition

I'm fairly new to programming and definitely new to Java. I'm teaching myself before I begin courses this fall in computer science and I have a curiosity about syntax that I have seen from two different authors.
In one book, a JFrame is usually established by making the class an extension of JFrame

```
public class MyClass extends JFrame {
```

etc

However, another author, and also questions on this site usually establish a frame inside of the class as such:

```
public class MyClass {
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
```

Firstly, what are the advantages of one over the other? 
It seems to me, and I'm hardly an expert, that making a class an extension of JFrame would make it easier to set parameters of the frame and also to add components to it.

IE in the extension format, you simply say

```
add(component);
```

However, in the other format, on must type:

```
frame.getContentPane().add(component);
```

which seems more tedious.

Can someone please explain succinctly the reason behind this or if it is simply a matter of preference. I have looked into this and have been unable to get a straight forward answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are philosophical and practical reasons many (including I) prefer the latter:

- Prefer composition over inheritance in general.
- Only extend a class if you plan to alter its innate behavior (i.e., override one or more of its methods).
- By not extending JFrame, it is easier to create classes that maximize cohesion and minimize coupling, and to write clean MVC-based code. A more important example of this concept is to avoid having your GUI code (your *view* code) implement any listener interfaces (your *control* code). It's OK for baby programs, but not for grown-up code that has the potential of getting complex.
- By not extending a large and complex class such as JFrame, you reduce the risk of difficult to debug hidden override malbehaviors. Try extending JFrame or JPanel and giving the class a `getX()` and `getY()` method to see what I mean!
- If you're using an IDE that gives suggestions of methods available to objects of your class, you greatly reduce the number (and complexity) of possible suggested methods if you don't override a huge complex class such as JFrame.
- By gearing your Swing GUI's to create JPanels rather than override JFrame, you greatly increase the flexibility of how that GUI can be used. Now it can be placed in a JDialog, JOptionPane, a JApplet, inside of another JPanel as part of a more complex GUI or as part of a CardLayout view swap.... and I can go on and on.
- On the same token as above, many of my GUI's do just that, create JPanels, that I can test in isolation by putting them in JFrames in small test programs before adding them to the greater whole of the application.

Comment: Thanks. Very good explanation. I greatly appreciate the examples and the time you put into your answer. It also made it really easy to understand the advantages and disadvantages of these two methods.

Answer (score 3):

Traditionally you're not creating a special type of frame, so you shouldn't extend JFrame.

You're creating a JFrame and putting content in it, so the latter method is preferrable.

I.e. it's from an object oriented point of view it's cleaner to USE a JFrame, instead of extending one.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Both answers provided have cleared up this dilemma for me and I greatly appreciate the time taken to answer this newb question.